# When did Hanuman worship Shiva?

Tags: shiva, hanuman

[image]

This picture shows Hanuman worshipping Shiva. Are there any references in Ramayana or Puranas of Hanuman worshipping Shiva? What is the background and purpose of that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about scriptural basis , but there is legend regarding this .
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kundala_Karaneswarar_Temple

> Hanuman worshipped Shiva seeking pardon for the offence of having tried to uproot the Shivalingam at Rameswaram.